# exception handling framework in spring java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, orientdb

This is my Controller class

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/profile/MyLink.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void MyLink(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody String data)
                throws JSONException {


        JSONObject profile = null;
        try {
            profile = new JSONObject(data.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
        }
        // Some code

        // calling the DAO method from where the exception will be thrown.
        } catch (Exception e) {

            // checking the thrown message from method
            if(e.getMessage() != null && e.getMessage().length() > 0){
                logger.info("Printing the error message " + e.getMessage());

                JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(e.getMessage()));
                reader.setLenient(true);

                //creating Java Object from the thrown message
                objException = gson.fromJson(reader, ExceptionBean.class);
            }

            returnProfile.setError("error");

            if(objException != null)
                returnProfile.setObjException(objException);
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }


    strReturnJsonString = gson.toJson(returnProfile);

    PrintWriter pw = null;
    try {
        pw = response.getWriter();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pw.write(strReturnJsonString.trim());
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
}
```

I am getting the thrown exception here in catch block.

Next is my DAO class where exception is caught and thrown.

```
    public boolean MyDaoMethod()
{


    boolean blnResult = false;
    String strInsertQuery =" some sql query"; 
    try {
        for (Vertex v : (Iterable<Vertex>) graph.command(
                new OCommandSQL(strInsertQuery)).execute()) {

    }
    catch(OCommandExecutorNotFoundException e2){
        logger.info("Printing whole exception !!! " + gson.toJson(e2.getStackTrace()));
        logger.info("Printing the further details for exception !!!! " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber());
        ExceptionBean objException = new ExceptionBean();
        objException.setStrExceptionCode("202");
        objException.setStrExceptionDesc("Cannot find a command executor for the command request : "+strInsertQuery);
        objException.setStrFileName(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getFileName());
        objException.setStrClassName(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName());
        objException.setStrMethodName(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());

        for(int i=0;i<e2.getStackTrace().length;i++){
            if(objException.getStrClassName().equalsIgnoreCase(e2.getStackTrace()[i].getClassName()) 
                    && objException.getStrMethodName().equalsIgnoreCase(e2.getStackTrace()[i].getMethodName())){
                objException.setStrLineNumber(""+e2.getStackTrace()[i].getLineNumber());
            }
        }

        String strExceptionObj = gson.toJson(objException);
        throw new OrientDBCommandException(strExceptionObj);
    }catch(OCommandSQLParsingException e1){
        logger.info("Printing whole exception !!! " + gson.toJson(e1.getStackTrace()));
        logger.info("Printing the further details for exception !!!! " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber());
        ExceptionBean objException = new ExceptionBean();
        objException.setStrExceptionCode("201");
        objException.setStrExceptionDesc("There is some kind of error in DataBase command parsing.");
        objException.setStrFileName(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getFileName());
        objException.setStrClassName(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName());
        objException.setStrMethodName(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());

        for(int i=0;i<e1.getStackTrace().length;i++){
            if(objException.getStrClassName().equalsIgnoreCase(e1.getStackTrace()[i].getClassName()) 
                    && objException.getStrMethodName().equalsIgnoreCase(e1.getStackTrace()[i].getMethodName())){
                objException.setStrLineNumber(""+e1.getStackTrace()[i].getLineNumber());
            }
        }

        String strExceptionObj = gson.toJson(objException);
        throw new OrientDBCommandException(strExceptionObj);

    }
         catch (Exception e) {
             logger.error(e);
     }      

    return blnResult;
}
```

I have created a custom exception class and used it in my DAO class.

Here is my custom Exception class

```
    public class OrientDBCommandException extends OCommandSQLParsingException{

String ObjException; 

public OrientDBCommandException(String ObjException) {
    super(ObjException);

    this.ObjException=ObjException;
}

public ExceptionBean getExceptionObj(String strExceptionCode){

    ExceptionBean objException = new ExceptionBean();

    return objException;


}
```

}

I am interested to know whether this approach is correct or not. And how can i use the method getExceptionObj created in custom exception class in controller class, if i can.

Tell me the way to implement custom exception class method to spring in java.

Answer (score 0):

This is not right.. never catch an excpetion, if you have no idea how to handle it, check out this link here, you should use `Exception handling in spring way` https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: I am rather not comfortable with the response status and defining the view for the error. My main aim is to catch the exception caused and create a object for it, which will define all the details related to the exception.

Comment: @DineshPurty Details should be thrown and caught by exception handler. In your way you just losing information about the actual cause of the exception

Comment: As you can see... I am gathering all the information in my catch block which is present in DAO class method. And, from there throwing to my custom exception class, which in return get collected in catch block of controller class. In controller class, I get all the required information about the exception caught.

Comment: @DineshPurty I see your point, this is doable.. but it is just not the best practice.. code is in your hand.. you can do whatever you want as long as it works ;)

Comment: ok..Thanks for the suggestions. Really appreciate it. If you had to do it, in your way, how would you have settled. can you give a sample demo.

Comment: @DineshPurty great demo from spring blog, check the link https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: I find use of @ControllerAdvice interesting and I am going to implement that, but I am interested to know, from this approach can I get the class name and line number, where the exception occurred.

Comment: @DineshPurty sure, actually one of the mistake you made in your example code is you forget to chain the exceptions..in this case, you will never know the root cause of the exception